# Persisting JSON with sequelize-typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to store a simple JSON-Array in a MariaDB using `sequelize-typescript`. Here's a basic Model that would work in PostgreSQL, SQLite and MySQL.

```
class MyModel extends Model<MyModel> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.JSON
  })
  options!: string[]
}
```

To get the same behaviour with MariaDB I tried four things:

### 1. Use `@AfterFind` or some other hook.

**Problem:** As stated in this [issue in the github repo](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4627), there's a known bug that hooks will not fire on included models, so no chance

### 2. Implement an own custom JSON Data-Type (preferred solution)

**Problem:** Even copying the [example in the sequelize-docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html#extending-datatypes) throws various typescript compiler issues and even If I use `any` types and trick the TS-compiler I don't know how to tell my other models that there is a new DataType.

### 3. Use a getter/setter for the same property

```
class MyModel extends Model<MyModel> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING
  })
  get options(): string[] {
    return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('options'))
  }

  set options(value: string[]) {
    this.setDataValue('options', JSON.stringify(value))
  }
}
```

This throws compiler errors for the `getDataValue`and `setDataValue` methods:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this["options"]'
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
```

### 4. Use a getter/setter for a private property

What would work is to just store the Array as a string in the DB and use a getter/setter to access & parse this property.

```
class MyModel extends Model<MyModel> {
  @Column
  _options!: string;

  get options(): string[] {
    return JSON.parse(this._options)
  }

  set options(value: string[]) {
    this._options = JSON.stringify(value)
  }
}
```

As I said, that works, but I'd rather like to have something more generic that works faster for a larger number of fields, like a custom datatype.

So my question is:
**Is there a convenient, short, easy, dynamic and reusable way to store JSON in a MariaDB?**